# Stop a tornado.TCPServer without waiting for connections to close

Tags: python, sockets, tornado

The docs for [`tornado.tcpserver.TCPServer.stop`](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/tornado/tcpserver.html#TCPServer.stop) say:

> Requests currently in progress may still continue after the server is stopped

However, to test for robustness I want to simulate a full crash of the server.

Is there a preferred way to abruptly terminate a tornado.TCPServer?  In particular I want to terminate all open sockets *ungracefully*.

#### Edit

So I don't think that `stop` fully terminates existing connections.  The following code prints `1, 2`

```
from tornado import gen
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.tcpserver import TCPServer
from tornado.tcpclient import TCPClient

port = 9000

class Server(TCPServer):
    @gen.coroutine
    def handle_stream(self, stream, address):
        while True:
            bytes = yield stream.read_bytes(5)
            yield stream.write(bytes)

server = Server()
server.listen(port)

@gen.coroutine
def client():
    client = TCPClient()
    stream = yield client.connect('127.0.0.1', port)
    yield stream.write(b'Hello')
    result = yield stream.read_bytes(5)
    assert result == b'Hello'
    print(1)

    server.stop()

    yield stream.write(b'Hello')
    result = yield stream.read_bytes(5)
    assert result == b'Hello'
    print(2)

IOLoop.current().run_sync(client)
```

Answer (score 1):

`TCPServer.stop` does exactly what you want; the comment you quoted is a warning that `TCPServer` makes no attempt at a graceful shutdown.

Comment: I don't think that `TCPServer.stop` does actually kill things.  I've included a minimal example as an edit in my original question above.

Comment: Ah, I see. This is difficult; the most ungraceful shutdown you can easily do is to run client and server in two separate processes, and kill the server process. But this still has a bit of grace; I think the kernel will still send RST packets.  To simulate the most ungraceful shutdown possible I think you'll need separate VMs, or at least manipulation of network interfaces.

Comment: Yeah, I've been using processes in the meantime.  Was hoping for the ability to debug across both the client/server while testing.  Alas.

Comment: How ungraceful do you need? You might be able to use threads instead of processes and then `IOLoop.close(all_fds=True)`. This will register as a relatively clean shutdown of the sockets, but they may be in the middle of other operations that could be interrupted.